# Convert Decode(case from oracle to sql server

Tags: sql-server, case

Hello I have this part of a script in oracle and I need to move it in Microsfot Sql Server:

```
CASE (DECODE(Employee.title, 'assistant',  
         nvl(Employee.title, 'NULL'))) 
      WHEN 'programmer' then 'level1'  
      WHEN 'engineer' then 'level2'  -

        ELSE 'other'  
        end as x,
```

Can someone please help me tell how it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand how `decode` functions, what you seem to required is:

```
CASE
    WHEN Employee.Title = 'assistant' THEN 'level0'
    WHEN Employee.Title = 'programmer' THEN 'level1'
    WHEN Employee.Title = 'engineer' THEN 'level2'
    WHEN Employee.Title IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
    ELSE 'other'
END AS x
```

Unfortunately, your `DECODE` statement does not seem to match the requirements.

For information, in Oracle SQL the `DECODE` is a form of `CASE` as follows:

```
select id, decode(status,'A','Accepted','D','Denied','Other')
from   contracts;
```

Will return for each id:

> If status = 'A' : 'Accepted'
>   If status = 'D' : 'Denied'
>   Else : 'Other'

Answer (score 0):

Your script is equivalent to this,

```
CASE Employee.title WHEN 'assistant' THEN 'assistant'
      WHEN 'programmer' then 'level1'  
      WHEN 'engineer' then 'level2'
      ELSE 'other'  
 END AS X
```

But  your original script from a logic point of view does not seems completely correct.

The section

```
DECODE(Employee.title, 'assistant',  
         nvl(Employee.title, 'NULL'))
```

seems to me to return always 'assistant'.

`If Employee.title = 'assistant'`  --> `THEN` get the first non null value between `Employee.title` and `'NULL'`.   But `Employee.title = 'assistant'`...